# mdx create new dimension from another one as substring

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I have the dimension 'Cities'.
Example:

'Paris'
'Moscow'
'London'

I need to create new Cities_Short_Name in `mdx` query where I can show first three letters. Examples: 'Par', 'Mos', 'Lon'. I can't change `DSV` on `SSAS`.

Comment: You can't change the DSV as in you can't add a named calculation? But you want it to be part of the dimension rather than a one time thing created in a query.  Is this correct?

Comment: @mmarie i can't add a named calculation because i have only a read permission for the cubes. I want to create the temporary dimensional in a query.

Comment: What are you using to consume the the data/make reports?

Comment: @mmarie MS SQL management studio. I need to create the MDX query with the changed values in the dimension.

Answer (score 3):

Your query will look something like the below. I made up the name of the dimension and the cube for this since you didn't specify anything other than that you have a dimension attribute called Cities.

```
with member [Measures].[Cities_Short_Name] as 
left([Geography].[Cities].currentmember.name, 3)

select [Measures].[Cities_Short_Name] 
on 0, 
[Geography].[Cities].[Cities].members on 1 
from [MyCube]
```

You will just need to replace the Geography dimension with whatever your dimension is called and MyCube with your cube name. This will return a list of cities and the associated abbreviation.